# Removing the last line from pd.Series.value_counts output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I did:

```
print(df['User Type'].value_counts())
```

This gives output:

```
Subscriber    238889
Customer       61110
Dependent          1
Name: User Type, dtype: int64
```

Is there any way to remove the last line `Name: User Type, dtype: int64`.?

Comment: This is not a line in your data. It is meta-data relating to your `pd.Series` object. If you want to `print` your series in a specific format, you need to specify exactly what you want.

Comment: Do you need `print(df['User Type'].value_counts().to_frame())` ?

Comment: No i didnt want to print this , i want to save the data in a variable , i got the solution , i converted the output to a dict and used it , thanks for responses.